# Guardar fecha al importar un excel con Laravel Excel

Tags: php, laravel, excel, laravel-excel

Necesito importar un excel a una tabla. Mi documento excel es este.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi clase import es este.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero por alguna razón no puedo guardar las fechas. La validacion para las fechas y al final me guarda un numero entero en la BD.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La columna fecha_ini esta como varchar y la columna fecha_fin esta como tipo DATE.

Pienso que es por el formato desde los datos de Excel, pero ya lo guarde con formato de Fecha corta.

Por cierto, el numero que me guarda en la columna fecha_ini es la fecha en formato General.

Comment: Hola, veo que eres nuevo en SO en Español, así que te recomiendo leer en [¿Comó preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tengas una clara idea de cómo formular una buena pregunta y edites la misma. [Usa bloques de código y no imágenes para plasmar tu código](https://es.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) aquí

Answer (score 0):

Espero esto te pueda ayudar, tenía el mismo problema, pero con este post pude solventar el inconveniente.

https://academy.leewayweb.com/como-tratar-con-fechas-en-excel-usando-php/